# Aligning text in a c# list control

Tags: c#, string, listview, formatting, text-alignment

I can find a smattering of examples, but not a detailed explanation for how text formatting works.  (Tons of information/examples for Python, for example).

I have

```
output_text = "Total pay on day " + day + " is " + total_running_pay.ToString("c");
```

where day and total running pay are integers.

This gives a list like:

```
Total pay on day 1 is $1
Total pay on day 2 is $3
Total pay on day 3 is $7
Total pay on day 4 is $15
```

etc.

I would like the dollar amounts to be right aligned.

Any suggestions?

Comment: WPF/Winforms/ASP.Net?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Next code should work:

```
output_text = String.Format("Total pay on day {0} is {1,10:c}", day, total_running_pay)
```